# How to present array object in select drop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array object and that to show in select tag using angular js only below object is my array object

```
"matcherObject": {
"Percentage Off": [
  {
    "dealType": "Percentage Off",
    "subCategory": "16% to 20%",
    "recid": 2
  },
  {
    "dealType": "Percentage Off",
    "subCategory": "10 to 15 %",
    "recid": 1
  },
  {
    "dealType": "Percentage Off",
    "subCategory": "21% to 25%",
    "recid": 3
  }
],
"Special Deals based on the event": [
  {
    "dealType": "Special Deals based on the event",
    "subCategory": "Buy 1 get one entr",
    "recid": 52
  },
  {
    "dealType": "Special Deals based on the event",
    "subCategory": "Buy 1 get one entr",
    "recid": 54
  }
]
};
```

This object I have to how in select tag please help me to solve this problem.
Below the image how to show in UI:

[image]

If I select tag the ng-model should show as below format as below

```
{"dealType": "Percentage Off","subCategory": "16% to 20%","recid": 2}
```

Comment: What you want to show in the dropdown?

Comment: drop down i have to show subCategory name

Comment: **Please help to slow this problem**

Comment: You're among fellow Web developers; if you mean "`<select>` tag", please say "select", not dropdown.

Comment: yes it is selet tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ng-options since you wish to select an object. See angular documentation for [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#!).

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope){
$scope.reqObj =     {"matcherObject": {
"Percentage Off": [
  {
    "dealType": "Percentage Off",
    "subCategory": "16% to 20%",
    "recid": 2
  },
  {
    "dealType": "Percentage Off",
    "subCategory": "10 to 15 %",
    "recid": 1
  },
  {
    "dealType": "Percentage Off",
    "subCategory": "21% to 25%",
    "recid": 3
  }
],
"Special Deals based on the event": [
  {
    "dealType": "Special Deals based on the event",
    "subCategory": "Buy 1 get one entr",
    "recid": 52
  },
  {
    "dealType": "Special Deals based on the event",
    "subCategory": "Buy 1 get one entr",
    "recid": 54
  }
]
}
};


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
<select data-ng-model = "selOption" data-ng-options="perc as perc.subCategory for perc in reqObj.matcherObject['Percentage Off']">
</select>

<hr />


{{ selOption | json }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have nested lists, you have to use `ng-repeat` twice, also give the `deal-type-name` in a `name` property so that you can display it.

I changed it a bit:

```
$scope.matcherObject = [{
    "listName": "Percentage Off",
    "items": [{
      "dealType": "Percentage Off",
      "subCategory": "16% to 20%",
      "recid": 2
    }, {
      "dealType": "Percentage Off",
      "subCategory": "10 to 15 %",
      "recid": 1
    }, {
      "dealType": "Percentage Off",
      "subCategory": "21% to 25%",
      "recid": 3
    }],
  }, {
    "listName": "Special Deals based on the event",
    "items": [{
      "dealType": "Special Deals based on the event",
      "subCategory": "Buy 1 get one entr",
      "recid": 52
    }, {
      "dealType": "Special Deals based on the event",
      "subCategory": "Buy 1 get one entr",
      "recid": 54
    }]
  }]
```

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-repeat="listItem in matcherObject" >
  {{listItem.listName}}
    <li ng-repeat="item in listItem.items">
        {{item.subCategory}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Check working example here: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AgGSsiLQ9KbeR4TDWxrg?p=preview)

**EDIT1:**

Following code will do your work withour changing the script:

```
<ul ng-repeat="listItem in matcherObject">
    <li ng-repeat="item in listItem">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="subItem in item">
          {{subItem.subCategory}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank u friend please we cant chage oject why because it is comin from back end

Comment: how itwill use in select tag

Comment: will u help me how to get this in select tag

Comment: You just have to write `select` and `option` for that!